# Using HttpContext for InfoPath 2007 codebehind

Tags: c#, infopath-2007

What am I doing wrong here please? I get a NullReferenceException.

```
string outUrl = "http://whatever.com";
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
context.Response.Redirect(outUrl, false);
```

When I use new like this:

```
HttpContext HC = new HttpContext();
```

I get No Overload for method.  I am working with .NET 2 inside VSTA.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the  tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpContext is not possible to instanciate and will only be created by your application.

It even really hard to mock (create a fake), Why do you need one ? what is your application type ?

Comment: In short, I need to mix rules and code with an InfoPath form.  I want to redirect the user to a webpage after they have clicked on the submit button.  I would also be fine with closing the form programatically, but that's also a challenge.

Comment: I ended up doing this in a different way with conditional formatting in InfoPath.  Thanks for the answer.  I didn't want to chase an empty solution.

Comment: I think you did well, it was just impossible.

Comment: I never added any detail here so: instead of redirecting, I added a section (with rules) saying thanks for submitting that would become the only visible element on the page once the form was submitted.